# Why is this question that appears historically significant deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, historical-lock

Questions that were once on-topic and popular, but are now off-topic, usually seem to be locked.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235848/most-astonishing-violation-of-the-principle-of-least-astonishment) seems to fit those criteria, but it's deleted (by Jeff himself).

Why?

Comment: Are you really asking why an off-topic question was deleted?

Comment: @Oded Was it off-topic in 2008?

Comment: It was off-topic in 2011, when it was deleted.

Comment: It's a question with hilarious answers, but "historically significant"?

Comment: @Pekka http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature is along a similar vein, and marked as historically significant.

Comment: @immibis programmers can actually learn something from that one because it contains useful programming-related info.

Answer (score 5):

Being from 2008 does not immediately make a question historically significant. Moreover, this question only lasted just over 2 years before being deleted.

In this entire time, it has accumulated a "massive" 6322 views, and that just does not strike me as significant. While it may have 105 upvotes, the post was a community wiki, and as a result the voting is skewed with comparison to a regular post.

Reading through the content in the answers, no one even attempts to address the issue of how to fix any of the observations and it reads more like an xkcd article than a Stack Overflow post.

Were it asked today, it would be removed quickly. At some point it was decided that it should not remain because of some of the metrics still used today, and Jeff Atwood (co-founder) deleted it.

Certain posts may be historically significant, but in general those are the posts which are [popular for the right reasons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/), and not just because they were used as a space for joking.

Here at Stack Overflow, [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

> On Stack Overflow, contrary to popular opinion, we don't hate fun. But only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated, and always with steely, businesslike frowns. :)

Comment: I mean, didja *really* have to resurrect this post?

Comment: @Makoto - It had no answer :( Perhaps if it had been closed or deleted we wouldn't be in this situation, pondering what could or could not have been in an obscure comment not likely to be read by anyone but us.